# Difference between "платить" and "отбашливаться"?

Tags: глаголы

Difference between "платить" and "отбашливаться"?

What's the difference between the two? Apart from the latter one being slang.

Comment: Never heard the second one. I assume it means to give a bribe. I wouldn't use it if I were you.

Comment: *Можно не сомневаться, что тот будущий юноша, который в 1973 году скажет, например, _рубать_ или _башли_, не встретит среди своих сверстников никакого сочувствия и покажется им безнадежно отсталым*. K. Chukovsky, 1962.

Comment: This "отбашливаться" word sounds very funny to me :)). Surely, most Russians does not know this word.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Отбашляться* means "to pay off someone", to avoid some kind of trouble by paying money: bail yourself out of jail, bribe an official who's threatening you with a legal penalty, pay someone whose car you have scratched on site to avoid dealing with insurance etc.

It's a slang word similar in meaning to neutral *откупиться* or *отплатиться*.

*Платить* is a neutral word meaning "to pay". Its slang counterpart with the same root would be *башлять*.

Answer (score 3):

*Платить* means simply *to pay*. About *отбашливаться*, I never heard such word, yet as there's jargon / colloquial *башлять* (or *забашлять*), it could be some arbitrarily made up reflexive/imperfective form of it.

Slanguish *башлять* means *to pay off* or *to bribe*.